# HTMLAgilityPack stripping out html

Tags: c#

I'm sure this question has asked before and i've looked before I cant find the answer, or maybe I am just doing something wrong.

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(indivdualfix[0]);             
                HtmlWeb hwObject = new HtmlWeb();
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmldocObject = hwObject.Load(indivdualfix[0]);
                HtmlNode body = htmldocObject.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
                body.Attributes.Remove("style");
                foreach (var a in body.Attributes.ToArray())
                    a.Remove();
                string bodywork = body.InnerHtml.ToString();
```

The string body still returns all the html coding.  I might be missing something really small here.  What needs to be doen to remove all the html coding basically.

Answer (score 3):

Use `body.InnerText` not `body.InnerHtml`